# Marketing Cloud email template non-editable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm trying to build an email template in Marketing Cloud, but when I place content into one of the content regions and save the email, when I return to it that region is no longer editable in any way.

I remember hearing ages ago about a character that would break the content regions and prevent it from unlocking, but I don't recall what it is.  Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *believe* the answer turned out to be `<br />`. The non-self-closing version `<br>` is fine, but the app doesn't seem to like self-closing HTML tags. Or at least that one.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same issue.  I am not using `<br>`, but your suggestion was actually helpful.

It appears that not only `<br/>` tags cause problems but also `<img .../>`, and probably all self-closing tags.

What is misleading is that the html editor is actually trying to correct the image tag every time the content is edited, so you have to check it (and change) manually every time before saving the content.

Comment: In general, asking follow-up questions as an answer is frowned upon. I've posted what seems to be the correct answer and checked it as "accepted." :-) thanks for reminding me to respond!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not my case - I am not using <br> or <br/> at all

Comment: I've change my comment to be a proper answer (because now I actually know what the problem is).